# Problem on norm linear spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces and let $T:X\to Y$ be a non-zero bounded linear operator. If $\alpha\geq 0$, I want to prove that $\inf\{\|x\|:x\in X,\|Tx\|=\alpha\}=\frac{\alpha}{\|T\|}$.

Let $A=\{\|x\|:x\in X,\|Tx\|=\alpha\}$.

Since $T$ is bounded, therefore, $\|Tx\|\leq \|T\|\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$. Thus $\frac{\alpha}{\|T\|}\leq \|x\|$ for all $\|x\|\in A$. Next how to proceed? Give a hint please!

Comment: The case $\alpha = 0$ is immediate. For $\alpha > 0$, we can by homogeneity constrain our considerations to the case $\alpha = \lVert T\rVert$.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Let $S(\alpha) = \{ x\in X : \lVert Tx\rVert = \alpha\}$. Then for $c > 0$ we have $S(c\alpha) = cS(\alpha) = \{ cx: x \in S(\alpha)\}$. That's the homogeneity. Now look at $S(\lVert T\rVert) = \{ x : \lVert Tx\rVert = \lVert T\rVert\}$ and look at some characterisation of $\lVert T\rVert$.

Comment: It means $S(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{\|T\|}S(\|T\|)$. Thus I have to prove that $\inf\{\|x\|:\|Tx\|=\|T\|\}=1$.

Comment: Yes. What definition and characterisations of $\lVert T\rVert$ do you know?

Comment: I have done it just now like this:
Let $x\in S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ and let $\|Tx\|>\|T\|-\epsilon$. Then $z=\frac{\|T\|}{\|Tx\|}x\in S(\|T\|)$ and $\|z\|<\frac{\|T\|}{\|T\|-\epsilon}=1+\frac{\epsilon}{\|T\|-\epsilon}$.